# pre render Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=%5Bobject%20Promise%5D

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

This is my page code todolist.js

```
    import Todo from "./todo";

const getTodos = async () => {
  let todos = await fetch("/api/todo/list");
  return todos.json();
};

export default async function TodoList() {
  const { todos } = await getTodos();

  return (
    <div>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
        {todos.map((t) => {
          return (
            <li key={t.id} style={{ padding: "5px 0" }}>
              
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

giving this error

```
> > my-next-app@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/7)
Error occurred prerendering page "/todolist". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=%5Bobject%20Promise%5D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:490)    at Zc (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89) 
    at Zc (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89) 
    at Zc (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89) 
    at $c (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)    at bd (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)(node:10420) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
undefined
info  - Generating static pages (7/7)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /todolist
    at C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:415:19
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1400:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1259:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:66:29)   
PS C:\Users\MazharKaunain\klll\my-next-app>
```

can anyone point to the source of the problem. i am running the sample from [here](https://github.com/tumetus/next-js-13-todo-app-example/blob/main/app/todo-list.js)

Comment: I guess the error lies in the Promise life cycle. It means it is rendering the rodoList data even before it actually has data. To resolve this use can either use todoList !== undefined or null check OR a Loading state which represents if the API is still processing

Comment: i understood what you are saying. how may i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like you are calling `todos.map` even before todo has any data, let's fix it by doing a simple value check using

`todos!==null && todos!==undefined && todos.length>0 &&`

```js
 import Todo from "./todo";

const getTodos = async () => {
  let todos = await fetch("/api/todo/list");
  return todos.json();
};

export default async function TodoList() {
  const { todos } = await getTodos();

  return (
    <div>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
        {todos!==null && todos!==undefined && todos.length>0 &&
         todos.map((t) => {
          return (
            <li key={t.id} style={{ padding: "5px 0" }}>
              
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also use Ternary for showing different cases such as

```js
{todos!==null && todos!==udefined &&
todos.length>0 ?
   // Render list with map

   :
   // Render list is empty
}
```

Comment: i think you may be right but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: i came accross https://github.com/isNan909/nextjs13-data-fetching/blob/main/app/server/page.jsx what do you think about use? i am looking into this

Comment: It is basically the same, but with modular code syntax

Comment: What else you can try is, doing better error handling with then() and catch(). It might be returning an err object right now as you are just returning the result which can be either list of task OR and err object